# Save thumbnail image to another folder [CodeIgniter]

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to create a thumbnail for the image that will be uploaded to my server. Refer to https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/image_lib.html#processing-an-image . After the creation, I want to save the thumbnail to another folder since both the original image and the thumbnail will be saved in the same location.

So, I try using `move_uploaded_file()` function but it unable to move the file. I'm not really sure if my code is correctly done. Check it out.

Belwo is the my code :

```
if($_FILES['file_name']['size'] != 0){
    $config['upload_path']          = FCPATH.MEDIA_LIB_URI.'facts';
    $config['allowed_types']        = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
    $config['max_size']             = 0;

    $newFileName = removeExt($_FILES['file_name']['name']).'-'.uniqueId();      // renaming the file name without the ext
    $new_name = $newFileName.getExt($_FILES['file_name']['name']);              // new file name with the ext
    $config['file_name'] = $new_name;

    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if($this->upload->do_upload('file_name')){
        $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
        $file_name = $uploadData['file_name'];

        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $configer = array(
            'image_library'   => 'gd2',
            'source_image'    => $uploadData['full_path'],
            'create_thumb'    => TRUE,
            'maintain_ratio'  => TRUE,
            'width'           => 950,
            'height'          => 950,
        );

        $this->image_lib->clear();
        $this->image_lib->initialize($configer);
        $this->image_lib->resize();

        $thumbName = $newFileName.'_thumb'.getExt($_FILES['file_name']['name']);    // getting the exact thumbnail name that been created by codeigniter
        move_uploaded_file($thumbName, FCPATH.MEDIA_LIB_URI.'facts/thumbnail/'.$new_name);

        return $file_name;
    } else {
        return $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
}
```

Comment: DId you get any error?

Comment: Didn't receive any. I end up using the `rename()` function to do the moving file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Use `new_image` in your `$configer` to change the folder path : `$config['new_image'] = '/path/to/new_image.jpg';`

**Note** : 
If only the new image name is specified it will be placed in the same folder as the original

If only the path is specified, the new image will be placed in the destination with the same name as the original.

If both the path and image name are specified it will placed in its own destination and given the new name.

*Your code should be like this :*

```
if($this->upload->do_upload('file_name'))
   {
        $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
        $file_name = $uploadData['file_name'];

        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $configer = array(
            'image_library'   => 'gd2',
            'source_image'    => $uploadData['full_path'],
            'create_thumb'    => TRUE,
            'maintain_ratio'  => TRUE,
            'width'           => 950,
            'height'          => 950,
            'new_image'       => FCPATH.MEDIA_LIB_URI.'facts/thumbnail/'
        );

        $this->image_lib->clear();
        $this->image_lib->initialize($configer);
        $this->image_lib->resize();
        return $file_name;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return $this->upload->display_errors();
    }
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html#CI_Image_lib::resize

Answer (score 1):

You found the right solution using rename or copy.

The reason it is not working with move_uploaded_file is because this function will only move the uploaded file which temporary name equals "tmp_name" in the $_FILES array.

The reason for this behavior is explained in the PHP manual: "This function checks to ensure that the file designated by filename is a valid upload file (meaning that it was uploaded via PHP's HTTP POST upload mechanism). If the file is valid, it will be moved to the filename given by destination. 
This sort of check is especially important if there is any chance that anything done with uploaded files could reveal their contents to the user, or even to other users on the same system."

As per PHP manual for POST method uploads:

$_FILES['userfile']['name'] = The original name of the file on the client machine. 
$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] = The temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server.

End quote

"tmp_name" is a unique server generated key so there is no filename duplication in the files system.

In your code, the $thumbnail string you built does not match "tmp_name" from the $_FILES array.

The reason you got no error message is because, again from PHP manual but for move_uploaded_file this time: "If filename is not a valid upload file, then no action will occur, and move_uploaded_file() will return FALSE."

Therefore, if you capture the result of move_uploaded_file in your code like $moveResult = move_uploaded_file(… you will end up with $moveResult === false. It is always a good idea to check the result of such an operation in order to react if something goes wrong.